# Simplify Haskell Code

Tags: haskell, monads, haskell-snap-framework

I'm working on Haskell code in the Snap framework. Everything works but now I need to clean up some code. However, after a few attempts, it seems I just have more code. Maybe anyone can give me some pointers?

This was my initial code. The thing is, I pattern match against a `Maybe` value which seems to me is very wrong. So I wanted to get that out of the way. But then the next line would get a `Maybe` value so I had to change that..

```
handleNewUserPost :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
handleNewUserPost = do
    Just username <- getPostParam "login"
    exists <- usernameExists $ T.decodeUtf8 username
    case exists of
        True    -> handleNewUserGet $ Just "Sorry, this username already exist."
        False   -> do
            registerUser "login" "password"
            redirect "/new_user"
```

Eventually I came to this:

```
handleNewUserPost :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
handleNewUserPost = do
    username <- getPostParam "login" -- :t username = Maybe ByteString
    validate username
    where 
      validate Nothing = redirect "/new_user"
      validate (Just username) = do exists <- existcheck username
                                    if exists
                                      then userexists
                                      else register
      existcheck :: C.ByteString -> Handler b (AuthManager b) Bool
      existcheck username = (usernameExists . T.decodeUtf8) $ username
      userexists          =  handleNewUserGet $ Just "Sorry, this username already exist."
      register            = do registerUser "login" "password"
                               redirect "/new_user"
```

The problem with this is that I have a feeling I shouldn't do a pattern match against the `Nothing` either. I'm in a `do`, so there should be something here. And the other thing is, I have a `do` in `register` as well. Any pointers are appreciated.

Comment: This may belong better on codereview.stackexchange.com. But basically I think your new code is fine. Bear in mind that you did actually make it more robust by adding the `validate Nothing` case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your new code. Part of the reason that it's longer than the original is that you are handling the `Nothing` case, which you weren't doing originally (so your new code is safer). If you wanted to neaten it up a bit, you could write it as

```
handleNewUserPost :: Handler App (AuthManager App) ()
handleNewUserPost =
  getPostParam "login" >>= maybe (redirect "/new_user") validateUser
 where
  validateUser username = do
    exists <- usernameExists $ T.decodeUtf8 username
    if exists
      then handerNewUserGet $ Just "Sorry, this username already exists."
      else do
        registerUser "login" "password"
        redirect "/new_user"
```

where I've used the function `maybe` from `Data.Maybe` to remove the need to explicitly handle the `Just` or `Nothing` values. This function is just defined as

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
maybe b _ Nothing  = b
maybe _ f (Just a) = f a
```